# Passing post data to other pages in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

This seems to work fine:

views/index.haml:

```
%form{:method => 'POST' :action => '/'}
  %label{:for => 'name'} Name:
    %input{:type => 'text, :value => @values[:name] || ""}
  %input{:type => 'submit'}
```

app.rb:

```
post '/' do
  @values = params
  haml :review
end
```

views/review.rb

```
Hello #{params[:name]}!
```

However, when I try to send my post-data to the same view on a different URL I get an error, or in other words:

app.rb:

```
post '/' do
  @values = params
  redirect '/review'
end

get '/review' do
  @values = params
  haml :review
end
```

The data is not going through, but no error is raised.

How do I send the post-data across pages like this? Ideally, I do not want to create a database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store the parameters in a session or specify the query string explicitly. [Browser Redirect from Sinatra Documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Browser%20Redirect)

As specified in the documentation, you may use sessions or convert the POST params to a query string and use it in the `redirect` method. A crude example would be:

Say the POST params hash inside the `'/'` block is:

```
{
  :name => "Whatever",
  :address => "Wherever"
}
```

This hash can be made into a string like so:

```
query = params.map{|key, value| "#{key}=#{value}"}.join("&")
# The "query" string now is: "name=Whatever&address=Wherever"
```

Now use this inside the `post '/' do`

```
redirect to("/review?#{query}")
```